# Add multiple columns and assign values to a dataframe from another dataframe columns based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
df1 = 


              Instance_name            counter_name         counter_value
              A                         bytes_read            0
              A                         bytes_written         90
              B                         bytes_read            100
              B                         bytes_Written          90
              C                         bytes_read            100
              C                         bytes_Written          90
```

I need to add columns to df1, based on df2 column "stage" done value. There can be multiple stages such as sort,comp,done etc. I am only interested in "done" stage rows.

```
df2 = 

load     instance_name    blks_comp   blks_sort  blks_dirty   stage 
0              A              0            50       90          sort
0              B              10           50       90          sort
0              C              10           50       90          comp

1              A              10           50       100         comp
1              B              910          950      9100        comp
1              C              980          950      9100        done

2              A              910          980      9100        comp
2              B              710          980      8100        done
2              C              910          980      9100        ready
```

If "instance_name" column fields has "done" stage, add these values to df1 dataframe. Output should be

```
df3 = 

    Instance_name counter_name counter_value  blks_comp   blks_sort  blks_dirty 
            A      bytes_read            0       0            0          0 
            A      bytes_written         90      0            0          0 
            B      bytes_read            100     710          980      8100
            B      bytes_Written         90      710          980      8100
            C      bytes_read            100     980          950      9100
            C      bytes_Written         90      980          950      9100
```

Instance Name has all 0s for blks_comp, blks_sort, blks_dirty as it doesnt have "done" value in stage column.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) of `df1` with the rows of `df2` where `stage == 'done'` on `Instance_name` and `instance_name`, dropping the unwanted columns and filling `NaN` with `0` where the merge doesn't match (because there's no matching instance row with stage `done` in `df2`):

```py
df3 = (df1
    .merge(df2[df2['stage'] == 'done'], left_on='Instance_name', right_on='instance_name', how='left')
    .drop(columns=['load', 'instance_name', 'stage'])
    .fillna(0)
)
```

Output:

```
  Instance_name   counter_name  counter_value  blks_comp  blks_sort  blks_dirty
0             A     bytes_read              0        0.0        0.0         0.0
1             A  bytes_written             90        0.0        0.0         0.0
2             B     bytes_read            100      710.0      980.0      8100.0
3             B  bytes_Written             90      710.0      980.0      8100.0
4             C     bytes_read            100      980.0      950.0      9100.0
5             C  bytes_Written             90      980.0      950.0      9100.0
```